# What does `@type t :: %__MODULE__{}` mean in Elixir

Tags: elixir

In std Elixir packages there are a lot of lines like

```
@type t :: %__MODULE__{}
```

I know that the `@type` annotation is used to alias short notation of type in `@spec` annotations, but this line is used in modules such as [uri.ex](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.0.4/lib/elixir/lib/uri.ex#L10) which has no `@spec` annotations at all.

What is the purpose of this annotation?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

First of all, types specified with the `@type` directive are **public** by default (as opposed to types defined with `@typep`). This means that even if a module has no specs in it, defining a type allows other developers to use that type when writing their functions:

```
@doc "Computes the length of a URI."
@spec foo(URI.t) :: non_neg_integer
def foo(uri), do: # ...
```

`__MODULE__` is a special form that expands to the current module name as an atom (see the [docs for it](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#__MODULE__/0)), so this:

```
defmodule MyModule do
  @type t :: %__MODULE__{}
end
```

will define a `MyModule.t` type. The most common use of the `t` type is for representing structs and protocols (e.g., `Enum.t`). This pattern is extremely common:

```
defmodule User do
  defstruct [:name, :email]
  @type t :: %__MODULE__{name: String.t, email: String.t}
end
```

Comment: About that `@typep` and `@type`. What is a meaning of `@opaque` than? I thought it's a type that is private

Comment: @KrzysztofWende `@opaque` types are public but they don't reveal the internal structure of the type (e.g., the fields in the struct are not public but the `t` type of the struct is. `@typep` types are completely private. Does it make sense?

Comment: it does. Partially. Why make type usable but not internally inspectable

Comment: @KrzysztofWende maybe you want to hide the complexity of the type but still expose the type in your public API?

Comment: can you specify a type in a way that the range of values is also specified / checked?
e.g. a type latitude should only have values between -90 and +90

Comment: @Tilo yes, `-90..90` is what you want in that case.

Comment: thank you, @whatyouhide! I have yet to find an example with a more complex type definition which does that kind of range checking. also: this should allow for floats